# How to make select and update at the same time python mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have an app that multiple users can connect to the same table at the same time. So I need an invoice number column which is a combination of Invoice_prefix and last invoice number. For example, if the last_invoice is 10 and the invoice prefix is ABC, then the invoice number should be ABC11. which is the last invoice incremented by one then combining both.

the invoice numbers should be unique. Currently what I have done is

```
cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
cursor.execute('UPDATE accounts SET last_invoice = last_invoice + 1 WHERE email=%s', 
              (email,))
mysql.connection.commit()
cursor.execute('SELECT CONCAT(invoice_prefix, last_invoice) from accounts where email=%s', 
              (email,))
```

But as there are multiple users accessing the website at the same time for the same client. I don't want a situation where the invoice number is duplicated. I can't give the UNIQUE property for the invoice number column because there are cases where it can be null.

Is this the only way to do this? Or is there a command that can assure me that the invoice number won't be duplicated even if multiple users click on the submit button at the same time?

Comment: You have 2 choices : 1: do both commands in a TRANSACTION , 2: use SELECT … FOR UPDATE

Comment: MySQL cannot UPDATE and SELECT in one query. Either 2 separate queries or stored procedure.